# Incompatibility between CDF document and reveal.js

Tags: cdf-format, html

I am making some [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/releases)-based slides with a CDF document embedded. The minimal example include the files:

```
<!-- test.md -->
# Title
<embed src="test.cdf"/>

(* test.cdf *)
Export["test.cdf", ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 20}]]
```

then convert `test.md` to `test.html` with [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/installing.html) via

```
pandoc -t revealjs -s test.md -o test.html
```

if you have put the folder `reveal.js` at the same place.

In my case, the CDF content is invisible in Firefox 39.0, but fine in IE 11. But if you remove the folder `reveal.js`, you can see the spiral in Firefox. So I guess there is some incompatibility between CDF and reveal.js.

Any ideas to get this around? Thank you.

**UPDATE**: the minimal test files can be downloaded [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1335302/revealjs_issue.7z).

And the slides also have the same problem (except that IE 11 works) if generated with [dzslides](http://paulrouget.com/dzslides/): putting the downloaded folder `dzslides` the same place as `test.md`, and similarly run

```
pandoc -t dzslides -s test.md -o test.html
```

to generate `test.html`. It may be easier to dig the lighter dzslides.

Comment: I doubt very much that there is a compatibility issue between the CDF itself reveal.js, there could however be something in the stylesheet/styles that reveal.js adds that makes displaces it or hides it, somehow. It would help troubleshooting if we had access to an HTML file with the problem, perhaps you can upload it somewhere (the public folder in Dropbox comes to mind.)

Comment: @Pickett Thanks for your interest. I added the download link for the test files. In the main text, reveal.js is the name of the slide framework that contains both `*.js` files and `*.css` files, and it is also the local name of the folder that keeps the files. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That's good, now we have sufficient information to debug it. I looked at it briefly but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: On my win10 chrome just claims the plugin is not supported. Edge won't load it too. However in IE and Yandex it looks fine.

Comment: @Silvia AFAIK CDF player only supports 32-bit browsers. Are your Chrome and Edge of 32-bit?

Comment: Chrome is 64bit version. Not sure how to check Edge.. But I'm on Win10 64bit.

Comment: @Silvia IE 32-bit and IE 64-bit are two different executables: one in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer` and the other in `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer`, so you can check the shortcut you use. But I have just found that IE 64-bit works fine. Maybe Wolfram has added the 64-bit support for IE undocumentedly.